# lldb - error: invalid thread #i

Tags: debugging, swift, lldb

I am trying to perform some debugging using LLDB on a buggy code:

```
@IBAction func somePrettyAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    let names = ["LLDB", "is", "fun", "Kudos :)"]
    println("out of index name: \(names[5])")
}
```

So when app crashed at println (for obvious reasons ;)), I typed -'Thread Info' at XCode debugger console, and it gave me below output:

```
thread #1: tid = 0x6fbc, 0x000000010ee5f1d0 libswiftCore.dylib`Swift._fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> () + 160, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

but when I typed - 't i', it showed below message:

```
error: invalid thread #i.
```

As per related wwdc video short form of given command should work, but for some reasons it is not working, any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, I noticed that too. [The presentation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=409) is incorrect. That's not the abbreviation for `thread info`. A suitable abbreviation now is `th i`.

Using `t` is the abbreviation for `thread select`. Thus, `t 2` is equivalent to `thread select 2`.

Type `help` at the `(lldb)` prompt, and it will show you a list of the current abbreviations.

Comment: Thanks it worked :) I tried help at (lldb) prompt but it did not display this particular short form (th i) :-|

Comment: The `help` only shows you the specially defined abbreviations. If you don't match one of those, it falls back to doing a word for word abbreviation (thus you can do `th i` or `thr in` or `thre inf` or any shortened version of `thread info` (_other than_ `t` which has the special definition).

Comment: thanks for your input.. your last comment was a jackpot for me ;) .. I tried playing with `brea li`, `th back` on (lldb) command console .. I owe you a beer for that :)